# Migrate Subversion to new server, different versions

Tags: linux, svn, fsfs

I need to migrate a number of svn repos:

From: Linux 32-bit, svn 1.6.11

To: Linux 64-bit, svn 1.8.10

The repos are using fsfs file system db.

What is the best way to migrate the repos? I don't mind having downtime during the migration.
Are there any implications going from 32-bit to 64-bit?

Can I install 1.8.10 on the destination and migrate direct to that? Or do I need to migrate to 1.6.11 and do an in-place upgrade to 1.8.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Best and The Shortest

- `svnadmin dump PATH/TO/REPO > dumpfile` on source
- `svnadmin create PATH/TO/REPO` on target (SVN 1.8 X64 is OK)
- `svnadmin load PATH/TO/REPO < dumpfile` on target

Comment: Thanks. when you say shortest do you mean quickest? Because I have 63GB to transfer and I know dump/load is really slow.

Comment: @MartinRennix - "shortest" is, well, *shortest in amount of handwork* - 3 non-interactive commands